# Can I fail the build if Karma didn't run all the tests?

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, tdd, mocha.js, karma-runner

Karma has the ability to limit which tests are run. For example, in Mocha if I change `describe` to `describe.only` only the tests in that suite will run.

It's great for TDD because I can focus on a subset of tests and get results much faster. However, I'm concerned about accidentally leaving in a `describe.only` when I check in so that the CI build doesn't run all the tests.

Is there a way to do either of the following:

- Force Karma to run all of the tests, ignoring `describe.only`, `ddescribe`, etc.?
- Find out if Karma only ran a subset of tests so that I can fail the build and alert the developer who accidentally left in a `describe.only`?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that Karma has such a feature (yet :)) so in the mean time I created a grunt task to scan the tests.

```
    grunt.registerTask('checkOnlyTests', 'Makes sure no define.only or it.only functions are left', function() {

    grunt.file.expand(['test/**/*.js']).forEach(function(f) {
        var contents = grunt.file.read(f);
        if (contents.search('describe.only') !== -1) {
            grunt.fail.warn('describe.only() found in ' + f);
        }

        if (contents.search('it.only') !== -1) {
            grunt.fail.warn('it.only() found in ' + f);
        }
    });
```